# cron zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

My magento cron job is failing with the following error:

```
zend_mm_heap corrupted
```

I've spent some time googling the problem but am still at a complete loss.

Comment: Which os / php version  / Magento version are you running ?

Comment: Centos, Apache, PHP 5.4.45, Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: I can run the file manually just fine, but when it is run by cron it fails with this error

Comment: Mage::registry('original_include_path') has an extra path in it which is causing the error. Where could this be added? How can I remove it?